# Why are only some hosts resolved using DNS?

Tags: networking, router, dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I have a DD-WRT router configured with DNSmasq. The config is

```
local=/myhome.local/
expand-hosts
addn-hosts=/jffs/hosts.dnsmasq
```

This way I can resolve network hosts (e.g. `ping macbookair`), but other hosts does not work. The following hosts work:

- The router itself
- My two macs

while the following do not work

- my AppleTV
- my Time Capsule
- iPhones/iPads
- my RaspberryPI (raspbian)

All hosts display their hostnames under the LAN status page on DD-WRT, so I assume the macs and the router do something special to set things up. Another difference is that the PI does not seem to pick up my local domain name (myhome.local).

What am I missing here?

Comment: you got everything up to date on the router & DNSmasq?http://superuser.com/questions/50372/snow-leopard-doesnt-like-dnsmasq

Comment: why won't you show your `/jffs/hosts.dnsmasq` as well?

Comment: /jffs/hosts.dnsmasq only contains a localhost entry pointing to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TLD `.local` is being used and abused by OSX, and other [MDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) services.  Trying to use `.local` on a devices that also run Bonjour(OSX)/Avahi(Linux) is going to be problematic.

Comment: I will try to change my local domain into something else and see if it helps.

Comment: I finally got around to fixing this. It turned out the hosts worked if I appended a period '.'. Changing DNS suffix so as not to conflict with mDNS will probably solve the problem, but for now I settled with just adding a .ssh/config host alias for the pi (i.e. to 'pi.') (which is the only non-mac I need to access ATM). Thanks!